# Arrays.filter not recognized as a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

So in the below code, I am trying to filter out tasks which are in incomplete status, but for some reason, the terminal says `tasks.filter` is not a function.

```
const tasks = {
    tasks: [{
        text: 'Grocery shopping',
        completed: true
    },{
        text: 'Clean yard',
        completed: false
    }, {
        text: 'Film course',
        completed: false
    }],

    getTasksToDo: function(){
        const completedTasks = tasks.filter(function(){
            return this.tasks.completed === false
        })
    }
}

console.log(tasks.getTasksToDo())
```

Comment: `tasks` is not an array. `tasks.tasks` *is*.

Comment: Just confused yourself naming the object variable the same as the property within the object

Comment: Title should be `object.filter` is not a function...

Answer (score 3):

I modified your code like this:

```
const tasks = { tasks: [{ text: 'Grocery shopping', completed: true },{ text: 'Clean yard', completed: false }, { text: 'Film course', completed: false }],

  getTasksToDo: function(){
    return this.tasks.filter(function(task){
        return task.completed === false
    });
  }
}

console.log(tasks.getTasksToDo())
```

The filter function callback takes a 'task' as an argument, you'll want to check completed against that, as that's each element inside `this.tasks`;

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `filter` on the object that is referred to by your `const tasks` constant. Instead, use `this.tasks.filter` or `tasks.tasks.filter` to refer to the `tasks` property on that object. (JavaScript has no concept of "implicit `this`" like Java or C# do.)

Your `filter` call is also incorrect. You're checking

```
this.tasks.completed === false
```

...but `this` within that call will be either `this` or the global object. Instead, accept the parameter and use it:

```
const tasksToDo = this.tasks.filter(task => task.completed === false);
```

or more idiomatically:

```
const tasksToDo = this.tasks.filter(task => !task.completed);
```

You could also throw destructuring at it:

```
const tasksToDo = this.tasks.filter(({completed}) => !completed);
```

Note I changed the name of the constant, since these are *incomplete* tasks, not completed ones.